# How to set default response on button with add_action_widget in Gtk.Dialog

Tags: python-2.7, dialog, gtk3

I loocking for any idea to solve my problem

Please see follow code.
It's a demo to explain what is about
In fact I need to use add_action_widget to add button in order to add button with image. If I mix add_action_widget and add_button widget are not the same vertical size and it's ugly.

I would like use only add_action_widget and be able to set valid button as default response

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8 
#dialog_defaultbutton.py
from gi.repository import Gtk

class boite_stockicon_etiquette:
    ''' box with STOCK Icon '''
    def __init__(self,text, stock_icon=None,sizeicon=Gtk.IconSize.MENU):
        # On cree une boite pour la pixmap et l'etiquette
        self.box = Gtk.HBox(False, 0)
        self.box.set_border_width(2)
        # A present l'image.
        if stock_icon is not None:
            image = Gtk.Image.new_from_stock(stock_id=stock_icon,size=sizeicon)             
        else:
            image = Gtk.Image.new_from_stock(stock_id=Gtk.STOCK_OK,size=sizeicon)                 
        # On cree une etiquette pour le bouton.
        etiquette = Gtk.Label(text)
        # pack image and label in the box
        self.box.pack_start(image, False, False, 3)
        self.box.pack_start(etiquette, False, False, 3)
        """image.show()
        etiquette.show()"""

    def box_xpm(self):
        return self.box 

class dialogDefaultButton:
    """ make button with stock icon"""
    def _make_button(self,etiquette=None,stock_icon=None):
        boite1= boite_stockicon_etiquette(etiquette,stock_icon=stock_icon)
        boite = boite1.box_xpm()
        bouton = Gtk.Button()    
        bouton.add(boite)    
        return bouton    

    def __init__(self,text):
        self.dialog = Gtk.Dialog(title="Dialog")

        self.dialog.set_default_size(400, 300)
        self.dialog.set_border_width(10)

        self.dialog.add_action_widget(self._make_button(etiquette=u'Valid',stock_icon=Gtk.STOCK_OK),Gtk.ResponseType.OK)   
        self.dialog.add_action_widget(self._make_button(etiquette=u'Cancel',stock_icon=Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL),Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL)

        #Please test under with True ou False
        flag_button_valide_setdefault = False

        #if flag_button_valide_setdefault is True the valid button is set like self.dialog.set_default_response(Gtk.ResponseType.OK)
        if flag_button_valide_setdefault is not True:
            self.dialog.add_action_widget(self._make_button(etiquette=u'Add', stock_icon=Gtk.STOCK_ADD),Gtk.ResponseType.APPLY)
            self.dialog.add_action_widget(self._make_button(etiquette=u'Help', stock_icon=Gtk.STOCK_ABOUT),Gtk.ResponseType.HELP)

        label = Gtk.Label(text)

        content_area = self.dialog.get_content_area()
        content_area.add(label)
        self.dialog.show_all()
        #Here action do not run ok why ?
        # Ok only with button created with   add_button



    def run(self):
        while 1:  
            self.reponse = self.dialog.run()
            if self.reponse in [Gtk.ResponseType.OK, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,Gtk.ResponseType.DELETE_EVENT]:
                print("OK sa marche button clicked")
                print self.reponse
                break
            else:
                print 'Hello'

        self.dialog.destroy()         
        return self.reponse

if __name__ == "__main__":
    demo = dialogDefaultButton(text= u'demo of default button depend widget list why?\n\
\n\
if flag_button_valide_setdefault == True , \n\
the valid button is set like self.dialog.set_default_response(Gtk.ResponseType.OK)\n\
if flag_button_valide_setdefault == False \n\
\n\
if somebody could help me to understand what is about !!!!!\n\
in fact I need to have flag_button_valide_setdefault =False\n\
and the valid button set with default response like case of flag==True')
    response = demo.run()
    if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
        print("OK button clicked")
    elif response == Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL:
        print("Cancel button clicked")
    else:
        print("Dialog closed")
```

Thank by advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

I found solution in order to manage button in Gtk.dialog.
When I tried to understand what is about with different type of Gtk.ResponseType. I discovered  sometimes is not possible to affect the button where I wanted….it's little suspect :-)
In fact after some test I found this. When you making a Gtk.dialog and  you preparing Gtk.Button separately and you adding this by  add_action_widget, the order of button's making is important. And also the type of response.
4 rules follow :

**rule 1:** in order to have a button with action like  set_default_response(response_id) you must declare this in first.

**rule 2 :** you could use any type of  Gtk.ResponseType with any stock icon. Gtk don't link it. Nevertheless to link a button with a label = ' Non OK' and a  Gtk.ResponseType.YES may be strange !!!! better way to keep a coherence between label and  Gtk.ResponseType….

**rule 3 :** an exception for Gtk.ResponseType.HELP.  The button made with self.dialog.add_action_widget(bouton_help,Gtk.ResponseType.HELP) is set firt left same if you making it in the last action and it was set default response

**rule  N°4 :** if you want use an help button and keep an other OK button set default response,
    make it first normally. After that make a button with something like that
button_help = my_method(label_help,stock_icon=Gtk.STOCK_HELP), where  my_method is making a button with a stock icon for example 
add button to the dialog…..
self.dialog.add_action_widget(bouton_help,Gtk.ResponseType.NO) . **Be careful to don't use a  Gtk.ResponseType.HELP  but to use  Gtk.ResponseType.NO** for example

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8 
#test_dialog_defaultbutton.py
from gi.repository import Gtk

class boite_stockicon_etiquette:
    ''' box with STOCK Icon '''
    def __init__(self,text, stock_icon=None,sizeicon=Gtk.IconSize.MENU):
        # On cree une boite pour la pixmap et l'etiquette
        self.box = Gtk.HBox(False, 0)
        self.box.set_border_width(2)
        # A present l'image.
        if stock_icon is not None:
            image = Gtk.Image.new_from_stock(stock_id=stock_icon,size=sizeicon)             
        else:
            image = Gtk.Image.new_from_stock(stock_id=Gtk.STOCK_OK,size=sizeicon)                 
        # On cree une etiquette pour le bouton.
        etiquette = Gtk.Label(text)
        # pack image and label in the box
        self.box.pack_start(image, False, False, 3)
        self.box.pack_start(etiquette, False, False, 3)
        """image.show()
        etiquette.show()"""

    def box_xpm(self):
        return self.box 

class dialogDefaultButton:
    """ make button with stock icon"""
    def _make_button(self,etiquette=None,stock_icon=None):
        boite1= boite_stockicon_etiquette(etiquette,stock_icon=stock_icon)
        boite = boite1.box_xpm()
        bouton = Gtk.Button()    
        bouton.add(boite)    
        return bouton    

    def __init__(self,text):
        self.dialog = Gtk.Dialog(title="Dialog")

        self.dialog.set_default_size(400, 300)
        self.dialog.set_border_width(10)

        # code de test pour voir l'ordre des boutons dans le widget
        self.dialog.add_action_widget(self._make_button(etiquette=u'Ok(-5)',stock_icon=Gtk.STOCK_OK),Gtk.ResponseType.OK)   #indice -5
        self.dialog.add_action_widget(self._make_button(etiquette=u'Cancel(-6)',stock_icon=Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL),Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL) #indice -6
        self.dialog.add_action_widget(self._make_button(etiquette=u'close(-7)', stock_icon=Gtk.STOCK_ABOUT),Gtk.ResponseType.CLOSE)#indice -7
        self.dialog.add_action_widget(self._make_button(etiquette=u'YES(-8)', stock_icon=Gtk.STOCK_ADD),Gtk.ResponseType.YES)#indice -8
        self.dialog.add_action_widget(self._make_button(etiquette=u'NON(-9)', stock_icon=Gtk.STOCK_ADD),Gtk.ResponseType.NO)#indice -9
        self.dialog.add_action_widget(self._make_button(etiquette=u'APPLY(-10)', stock_icon=Gtk.STOCK_ADD),Gtk.ResponseType.APPLY)#indice -10
        # do not use in case of need like these self.info_dlg.set_default_response(Gtk.ResponseType.OK)
        # please check line below with # or not
        self.dialog.add_action_widget(self._make_button(etiquette=u'HELP(-11)', stock_icon=Gtk.STOCK_ADD),Gtk.ResponseType.HELP)#indice -11
        """
        # three next button run ok also Gtk doc may be not update :-)
        self.dialog.add_action_widget(self._make_button(etiquette=u'ACCEPT(-3)', stock_icon=Gtk.STOCK_ADD),Gtk.ResponseType.ACCEPT)#indice -3
        self.dialog.add_action_widget(self._make_button(etiquette=u'REJECT(-2)', stock_icon=Gtk.STOCK_ADD),Gtk.ResponseType.REJECT)#indice -2
        self.dialog.add_action_widget(self._make_button(etiquette=u'FONCTION(42)', stock_icon=Gtk.STOCK_ADD),42)#indice -2
        """        
        label = Gtk.Label(text)

        content_area = self.dialog.get_content_area()
        content_area.add(label)
        self.dialog.show_all()

    def run(self):
        while 1:  
            self.reponse = self.dialog.run()
            if self.reponse in [Gtk.ResponseType.OK, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,Gtk.ResponseType.DELETE_EVENT]:
                print("run OK button clicked (sa marche )")
                print "Gtk.ResponseType is ", self.reponse
                break
            else:
                print 'Hello'
                print "Gtk.ResponseType is ", self.reponse

        self.dialog.destroy()         
        return self.reponse

if __name__ == "__main__":
    demo = dialogDefaultButton(text= u'demo de bouton pour montrer que tout bouton positionné avec un signal de type\n\
Gtk.ResponseType.HELP va avoir une position isolée des autres boutons et même gardera un écart.\n\
\n\
Demo in order to show how manage order button in Gtk.dialog.\n\
Gtk.ResponseType.HELP "give an order" to put help button on the left et the default become help button ')
    response = demo.run()
    if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
        print("OK button clicked")
    elif response == Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL:
        print("Cancel button clicked")
    else:
        print("Dialog closed")
```